# rename a file removing part of the filename batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have some files in the form:

> ```
> filename1 1 extra1.ext
> filename1 2.ext
> filename1 3 extra2.ext
> ...
> filename2 1.ext
> filename2 100 extra3.ext
> ...
> filename20 1.ext
> filename20 15 extra100.ext
> (etc.)
> ```

...where `filename1`, `filename2`, etc., can contain spaces, symbol `'` but not numbers. And `extra1`, `extra2`, etc, can contain anything. The number in the file name enclosed by spaces does not repeat per same `filename1`, `filename2`, etc.

What i want is to remove the extra things of the files that contain it. That is, to get from `filename20 15 extra100.ext` to `filename20 15.ext`

My first attempt is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FILE=file name 11 con sosas extras 2.txt"
set "ext=txt"
set "folder=."

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789" %%A in ("!FILE!") do (set "EXTRA=%%B")
set "FIRST=!FILE:%EXTRA%=!"
set "filename=!FIRST!.!ext!"
echo !EXTRA!
echo !filename!
echo rename "!folder!\!FILE!" "!filename!"
```

that seems to work, but if i change it to receive parameters, it doesn't:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "FILE=%1"
set "ext=%2"
set "folder=%3"

for /F "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789" %%A in ("!FILE!") do (set "EXTRA=%%B")
set "FIRST=!FILE:%EXTRA%=!"
set "filename=!FIRST!.!ext!"
echo !EXTRA!
echo !filename!
echo rename "!folder!\!FILE!" "!filename!"
```

where %1 is the filename, %2 is the extension and %3 is the folder in which the files are. Probably, the extension can be extracted inside the batch, but i don't know how to do it.

On another hand, i plan to use this batch into another one. There, there will be a for loop in `(*.txt)` and i don't know how to differentiate between files that have extra things (and then call this batch) from files that doesn't (and then not call this batch).

Regards,

Comment: So the final file names should look like `filename1.ext`, according to your examples, right? so does the number enclosed within spaces need to be removed too?

Comment: it should be from `filename1 15 extra100.ext` to `filename1 15.ext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a batch script that seeks the first purely numeric string portion enclosed within <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, or in case it appears at the end, preceded by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, that occurs after some other text not consisting of <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> only. The part in front of the found number followed by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> followed by the number itself are used for building the new file name.

This approach handles all valid characters for file names properly, even `^`, `&`, `%`, `!`, `(` and `)`.

So here is the code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=.\test"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B "%_SOURCE%\*.ext" ^| findstr /R /I ^
        /C:"^..* [0123456789][0123456789]*\.ext$" ^
        /C:"^..* [0123456789][0123456789]* .*\.ext$"
') do (
    set "FILE=%%F"
    call :SPLIT FIRST NUM REST "%%~nF"
    if defined NUM (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        ECHO rename "!_SOURCE!\!FILE!" "!FIRST! !NUM!%%~xF"
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:SPLIT  rtn_first  rtn_num  rtn_rest  val_string
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "RMD=" & set "NUM=" & set "STR=%~4"
    :LOOP
    for /F "tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%I in ("%STR%") do (
        if not "%%J"=="" (
            (for /F "delims=0123456789" %%L in ("%%J") do rem/) && (
                if not "%%K"=="" (
                    set "STR=%%J %%K"
                    goto :LOOP
                )
            ) || (
                set "NUM=%%J"
                if not "%%K"=="" (
                    set "RMD=%%K"
                )
            )
        )
    )
    set "STR=%~4"
    if not defined NUM goto :QUIT
    set "STR=%STR% "
    call set "STR=%%STR: %NUM% =|%%"
    for /F "delims=|" %%L in ("%STR:^^=^%") do set "STR=%%L"
    :QUIT
    (
        endlocal
        set "%~1=%STR%"
        set "%~2=%NUM%"
        set "%~3=%RMD%"
    )
    exit /B
```

After having tested the script, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually rename any files.

Comment: thanks!! I modify it by adding the _SOURCE and extension as entry parameters. Can i run this script inside another one without issues? I prefer to keep this one in a separate file...

Comment: To have this script in a separate file, use the [`call` command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html), then it should work just fine...

Answer (score 2):

use your method to extract the "extra-portion". In a second step, remove that extra-portion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "FILE=file name 11 con sosas extras 2.txt"

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=1234567890" %%a in ("%file%") do set new=!file:%%b=!%%~xb
echo %new%
```

`%%~xb` gives you the e**x**tension.

Comment: I am afraid this fails in case the extra portion appears in the preceding file name part as well; in addition, some characters cause trouble: `=` and `~` (when at the beginning)...